# VBA Code Won't Work if Any Cells Protected

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a shared workbook that needs to have a set amount of protected cells.  I also cut and pasted some VBA code into the workbook that allows multiple data validation drop down selections for the same cell (you can pick more than one of the drop down items).  The VBA works great until I protect the sheet.  By the way, the cells that are affected by the VBA code are not protected.  Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What type of protection are you using? Are you getting an error message? What version of Excel?

Comment: I am protecting the sheet, with a many of the cells unlocked.  If I unprotect the sheet, the VBA works.  If I don't, it doesn't.  Also, I don't get an error message, the VBA just doesn't work.  So the drop down menus only allow 1 selection rather than multiple.

Comment: When I protect a sheet (default options, only selecting is allowed), my VBA macros either a) work fine, because they don't try to change anything, or b) fail with a End-Debug dialog because they tried to change a locked cell. Since you're not getting an error, it might be best to try to isolate the problem in a small test workbook, and post the VBA code that's not working.

Comment: I can show you the code that stops running when worksheet protected.  I copied directly from a

Comment: If you can't post the code then we probably can't help you.  If its not changing protected cells it should run fine.  Take a look at which line is causing the error and possibly post that with other lines that set the ranges.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Developed by Contextures Inc
' www.contextures.com
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 14 _
  Or Target.Column = 22 Then

Comment: If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
'      NOTE: you can use a line break,
'      instead of a comma
'      Target.Value = oldVal _
'        & Chr(10) & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Let me know if there's a better way to cut and paste the code.  I'm new to this site.  I know that looks pretty unreadable.

Comment: Paste the code in your answer.  Press Edit.  Then Paste your code.  Then highlight the code and press Ctrl+K then click save edits.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I actually contacted the site Contextures, where I got the code from, and they said this code won't work with protected sheet.  They gave me corrected code if anyone wants me to paste.  Thanks again!